# Google Sheet Query: Select misses data when there are different data type in a column?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a table like this：

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | abc |
| 2 | 3 | 4.00 |

note c2 is text while c3 is a number.
When I do

```
=QUERY(A1:C,"select *")
```

The result is like

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 4.00 |

The "text" in C2 has been missed. You can see the live sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UOiP1JILUwgyYUsmy5RzQrpGj7opvPEXE46B3xfvHoQ/edit?usp=sharing

How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

QUERY is very useful, but it has a main limitation: only can handle one kind of data per column. The other data is left as blank. There are usually ways to try to overcome this from inside the QUERY, but I've found them unfruitful. What you can do is just to use:

```
={A:C}
```

You can work with filters by its own, but as a step-by-step to adapt the main features of query: If you need to add conditions, use LAMBDA INDEX and FILTER

For example, to check where A is not null:

`=LAMBDA(quer,FILTER(quer,INDEX(quer,,1)<>""))({A:C})` --> with INDEX(quer,,1), I've accesed the first column

Where B is more than one cell and less than other:

```
=LAMBDA(quer,FILTER(quer,INDEX(quer,,2)>D1,INDEX(quer,,2)<D2))({A:C})
```

---

For sorting and limiting an amount of items, use SORTN. For example, you want to sort by 3rd column and limit to 5 higher values in that column:

```
=LAMBDA(quer,SORTN(FILTER(quer,INDEX(quer,,1)<>""),5,1,3,0))({A:C})
```

Or, to limit to 5 elements without sorting use ARRAY_CONSTRAIN:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(LAMBDA(quer,FILTER(quer,INDEX(quer,,1)<>""))({A:C}),5)
```

There are other options, you can use REGEXMATCH and other options, and emulate QUERYs functions without missing data. Let me know!

Comment: I don't see how your answer solve the problem. For the sample data in my question, how should I write the query formula so everything could be properly selected?

Comment: It's correctly selected. QUERY only can handle one type of data, the one that it considers as in major quantity in your data. QUERY is filtering your data because it's considering C column as numbers and not text.  When you add enough text in a column, then it will appear because it will consider that column as text (and the numbers in that column as text too). I'll post a gif at the end of the post as you can see what I mean

Comment: I cannot upload a long enough gif. Just try adding some random text to any column and you'll see that eventually it will startt to "appear" in that column, because the type of data will be "changed" for majority of text instead of numbers